# Drupal6 - Export bulk node

Tags: drupal-6

Suppose I have 100 nodes in content type of "product", I would like to export these nodes to a .sql or .csv file, could anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to create a view of all your products, then use the [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) module to export to CSV format. There are lots of other Views add-ons that could be used to export in other formats, if needed.

However, it may depend on what you ultimately want to do with the exported nodes. If you need to import them into another Drupal site, I'd recommend checking out the [Node Export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) module, which has its own export/import format.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I know the module of "Node Export", but I dunno how to use it to export bulk node. Do you have any reference?

Comment: Go to the Content page (Admin > Content management > Content > List), select the nodes you want to export, then choose *Export nodes* from the *Update options* select list and click on the *Update* button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [node_export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export) module with [Drush](http://drush.ws/) from the command line in the root directory of your Drupal installation to export all nodes to a CSV file with the command:

```
drush node-export > export.csv
```